# What does the /conservative flag for tf merge do?

Tags: tfs

The documentation for the tf merge command specifies that the /conservative flag:

*"Results in more conflicts when you merge one branch to another."*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd6dxhfy.aspx

This is really a vague description, what does this flag actually do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the 2010 version, TFS has some improvements on merge conflict handling which results in less conflicts being generated. However, if you want the old behavior of TFS 2005 and TFS 2008, you can specify this flag when running the merge.

Chandru talked about this in details in his blog post:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chandrur/archive/2010/04/23/improved-merge-conflict-handling-in-tfs2010.aspx

Basically:

> 1. Rename / Undelete roots are no longer conflicts - in TFS 2005/2008
>      all renames, undeletes were
>      conservatively marked as conflicts.
>      This is no longer the case. Renames /
>      Undeletes will be merged
>      automatically.
> 2. In a previous post I had talked about how a resolution of keep yours /
>      accept merge in 1 direction would
>      result in a conflict in the opposite
>      direction. We have changed the default
>      behavior so these are auto-resolved.